# how to making an idle game using java

Tags: java

hi i'm tring to make idle game,
but i have some problem i want that every one sec X money will add to the player's currency
and to show the value in Jframe
i know to use with Threads but i dont know how.

```
package idle;
```

class MyThread extends Thread{

```
int cash;
    public MyThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }


public void run() {

    while(true){

        try {
            cash++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {


            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(getName()+ " " + cash);
    }
```

Comment: you want to run a thread or add x amount to currency ?

Comment: check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

Comment: @Mr.AF add X amout every sec and display it in jframe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: `will add to the player's currency and to show the value in Jframe i know to use with Threads`  - You should NOT be using a Thread. Updates to Swing components should be don't on the `Event Dispatch Thread` (see the "Concurrency" link given in above comment). Instead you should be using a `Swing Timer`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
public MyThread(String name, ThreadContext context) {
    super(name);
    this.context = context;
}
```

class ThreadContext

```
public class ThreadContext {
    private int cash;
}
```